# Sphinx / Solr for keyword / frequency queries

Tags: mysql, solr, sphinx

We need to be able to perform two types of queries efficiently against a table containing several million records:

1) Return the "x" most recent records which contain keyword "y".

2) Return the "x" most frequent keywords for a group of records.

We have been thinking about using some external search server such as Sphinx or Solr, but we are not sure if any of those will be able to support both types of queries.

So, which is the most efficient way to be able to perform those types of queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr can definitely do both of those things, assuming you've set up your schema.xml file properly. Your queries might look something like this:

```
1 - http://localhost:8983/solr/solr-index/select?q=y&rows=x&sort=date+desc

2 - http://localhost:8983/solr/solr-index/select?q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=description
```

In fact your main problem with Solr might be getting the data into the index. But even indexing and optimization are fast.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx can do 1) without even breaking a sweat. No problem them.

2) Is more tricky. Its not supported out of the box. But it can be done. Need to do a fair amount of extra work. Basically you need to tokenize the text yourself, and store ids as Multi-Value attribute. Can then run group by query on this mva column.

If the above sounds in anyway scary, you probably best using another solution - from the last reply sounds like Solr will do it.